# Failed to start login service

Tags: boot, 18.04, login

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 2 days ago, shut down the laptop, and when I started it the next morning, I got the error message on the black screen.

Yesterday, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 again. This morning, I shut down the laptop (without unmount ing external hard drives) , came to my office and tried to log in. I can't log in because of an error message (see the attached photo). Is there a simple solution?

"systemctl status NetworkManager.service" command in root returns inactive (dead)

[image]

Comment: Can you run the "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" ? and the one for login ? Cant tell you what is wrong just from this picture.

Comment: I am a bit uncertain whether you still have a getty spawned in this situation to actually log on to a console. As you mentioned that it happens sporadically, you might have already tried rebooting the system. Can you check the log files/journal for errors reported in that specific boot cycle? You could also check logind.conf for some less common settings which could be broken on your setup. Any unusual pam modules/external auth depending on the network?

Comment: Is it possible to reboot in recovery mode?

Comment: @Jos, yes I have access to advanced options and from there to root

Comment: What do the `systemctl status` commands tell you about why these processes (esp. the Login Service) couldn't be started?

Comment: @Jos, could you please give me complete commands?

Comment: They are there in the picture.

Comment: NetworkManager.service returns. Loaded: loaded. Active: inactive (dead).   systemd-loging. service returns same as NetworkManager.service